# code duplication in conditional Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, typescript

I am writing a function in Typescript that involves checking a condition, doing some extra processing if the condition is satisfied, and then doing the bulk of the job.

Here's the catch: the extra processing stuff, that runs if the condition is satisfied, returns a promise. So instead of a clean, simple solution like this:

```
function openDoor(door) {
    if(door.locked) {
        door.unlock();
    }
    door.handle.turn();
    door.handle.push();
}
```

It turns into some horrible mess, like this:

```
function openDoor(door) {
    if(door.locked) {
        door.unlock().then(() => {
            door.handle.turn();
            door.handle.push();
        });
    } else {
        door.handle.turn();
        door.handle.push();
    }
}
```

Why, you ask?

Unlocking the door takes some time, and I can't turn and push the handle until it's done. Without code duplication, I wouldn't have time to unlock the door before pushing it.

**So how can I make this better?**

In the shortened example above, the duplicated section is quite small, but troublesome nonetheless. I would like to be able to make changes in a single place rather than two, when I update the code. So, how can I avoid code duplication while keeping my Promise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could move the door.locked check into the door.unlock() function (or into a new function) which would allow you return a promise for both cases:

```
function unlockDoor(door) { 
   return door.locked 
          ? door.unlock()
          : Promise.resolve();
   }  
}

function openDoor(door) {
    unlockDoor(door).then(() => {
            door.handle.turn();
            door.handle.push();
        });
}
```